# R argument to answer "no" to "install from source that require compilation"?

Tags: r, compilation, install.packages

Is there an argument to the functions `install.packages()` or `update.packages()` to set to "no" when asked whether to install from source that require compilation?

The reason I'm asking is that I try to use the package `renv` and I know that some of the users of my projects will not have Rtools installed. So I would like to avoid issues here but I would also like to avoid the pop-up window asking for my input!

Comment: Yes there are options and I suggest reviewing the help page for `?install.package()`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
options("install.packages.compile.from.source" = "never")
```